# Android notificaciones diferentes

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-notifications

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]cómo resolver ese fallo, cuando la aplicación está encendida me muestra todo y cuál la programe, pero cuando está apagada me sale ese punto, no vibra ni timbra, por favor ayúdeme a resolver este fallo

```
    private void vernotificacion(String title, String body) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificacionBuilder =new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_icono)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 500, 1000,500,1000,500,2000})
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS )
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setContentIntent(pi);

    android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (android.app.NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Random random = new Random();
    notificationManager.notify(random.nextInt() , notificacionBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Revisa tu código tienes otro método que esta generando la notificación sin esos iconos.

Comment: Si la aplicacion esta cerrada y llega una notificacion, esta es manejada por el sistema operativo sin ejecutar tu aplicacion. Entonces se mostrará con los datos que tiene disponibles. Es por eso que no vibra ni timbra, ni hace nada de lo que vos pongas en el codigo, tu codigo simplemente no se ejecutará. Una forma de resolverlo es poner los campos que quieras mostrar dentro de Data asi el sistema operativo no sabe como manejar la notificacion y se ve obligado a ejecutar el codigo de tu app para mostrar la notificacion.

Comment: Saludo gracias por su respuesta, pero podría detallarme aque archivo o cosa te refieres con la palabra Data?

Comment: Revisa en tu código si generas otra notificación usando NotificationCompat.Builder @LosYondris

Comment: No, no tengo otra notificación solo esa, estado investigando y al parecer muchos están pasando por ese error, que la app cerrada muestra otro tipo de notificaciones.

Comment: Saludo @ErickSilva por favor me podría explicar mas detalladamente, la parte donde dices que coloque el código.

Comment: LosYondris, no te pedi que agregues mas codigo, solo digo que no ejecuta tu codigo porque el sistema operativo se encarga de presentar la notificacion cuando la app esta cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por editar tu pregunta! el punto que te refieres es en realidad el icono definido en la notificación como:

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_icono)
```

Veo que tampoco se muestra la imagen de la ambulancia definida por:

```
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes tener otro método que esta generando la notificación sin estos elementos.