# Switch en recyclerview Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, recyclerview

Saludos cómo puedo guardar el estado de los **`switch`**, en un `recyclerview`,

Lo que quiero es que cuando lo pongan en **off/on** no cambie su estado amenos que el usuario lo quiera

Comment: Es relacionado a esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286512/android-notificaciones-diferentes

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final listaPersonasAdater holder, final int position) {

     holder.mySwitsh.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            holder.myContext = compoundButton.getContext();

                if (compoundButton.isChecked() == true){
                     Toast.makeText(holder.myContext,"Actiado: "+compoundButton.isChecked(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(holder.myContext,"Desativado: "+compoundButton.isChecked(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

         }
     }); }`
```

Answer (score -1):

El **switch** (on/Off) lo tienes a nivel de cada ítem, es decir lo tienes en el adaptador verdad ?

Si es así solo debes agregar estas lineas de código a nivel del adaptador.

> @Override
>       public int getItemViewType(int position) {
>           return position;
>       }

Comment: Wilmer gracias lo probaré

Comment: Dale me comentas que tal te fue

Comment: no se si lo estoy haciendo bien poro no me funciona, cuando pongo el switch en ON y cambio de Activity vuelve a su estado normal off

Comment: Pero debes guardar el estado en algún lado, eso que te pase funciona a nivel de vista, para cuando realices Scroll no se pierda el cambio, ahora si deseas que sea permanente, debes guardar un estado, para cuando se consulte nuevamente ya venga con ese estado en "activo" y puedas manejar la vista.

Comment: Ese es el punto, que no se como realizar está acción,